# find columns in all database

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have a database `some_database` with multiples tables like:

```
table_one
table_two
table_three
```

where

`table_one` has `CPV_one`

`table_two` has `CPV_two`

`table_three` has `CPV_three`

I need to find all tables that have a column like `'%CPV%'`

This can be done by sql query? I want to avoid check all tables one by one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can query `information_schema` to get a list of each table in your database with a matching column name:

```
SELECT
    TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME

FROM
    information_schema.COLUMNS

WHERE
    TABLE_SCHEMA = 'SOME_DATABASE'
    AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%CPV%'
```

**EDIT** (selecting only the `TABLE_NAME` column)
As pointed out in a comment, if you want to select only the name of the table (without the list of columns that match), you should also use the `DISTINCT` keyword - otherwise a duplicate row will be returned for the same table for each column that matches:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT TABLE_NAME
FROM
    information_schema.COLUMNS
WHERE
    TABLE_SCHEMA = 'SOME_DATABASE'
    AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%CPV%'
```

Comment: Adding a `DISTINCT` on `TABLE_NAME` will prevent from listing several unnecessary rows, each one for each column with `%CPV%` string, in case there is more than one ofcourse

Comment: @Yaroslav You are correct, except my query selects the table name *in addition to* the column name - so there are no duplicate rows. The only reason to add `DISTINCT` would be if you wanted to return *only* the table name (without the column) and there are multiple columns matching the `'%CPV%'` condition in a given table.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have the code to get the table names with the needed condition:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME
  FROM information_schema.Columns
 WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%CPV%';
```

For more details on the **`INFORMATION SCHEMA`** [take a look here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html)

And for **`COLUMNS`** [table here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/columns-table.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%CPV%'
        AND TABLE_SCHEMA='YourDatabase';
```

Answer (score 0):

How about querying the MySQL information_schema?

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME
  FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
 WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%CPV%'
```